# run function with n params

Tags: c, function, undefined

I need to solve one problem in a virgin ANSI C (1989).

I have some pointer (void *func) to function with (int n) double parameters, and have array `double values[]` with `n` numbers. So I want to run my function with `n` param that are located in value.

For example, I have function:

```
double hypotenuse(double x, double y, double z);
```

so

```
void *func = (void *)hypotenuse; double values[3] = {5, 4, 3}; int n = 3;
```

and I want to do something like this:

```
func(n, values);
```

The problem is that I can't change the prototypes of the functions,
so I need to do this somehow (maybe some macros?).

Comment: A wrapper function with [variable length arguments](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson17.html) or that takes an array?

Comment: Macros could be used, or a wrapper function. But it's going to be messy.

Comment: @Dukeling, i don't mind what it will take, i need to run fuction with n parametrs, and i can't see how variable length arguments function can solve it.

Comment: Perhaps first learn to speficy a problem in such a way, that other do understand. Doing so often helps oneself to solve the issue ... ;-)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i can't see how i can use wrapper function here, i need to convers void *func to (*func)(double, double, ...) with n params

Comment: So you want: `double hypothetical(int n, double *v) { return hypotenuse(v[0], v[1], v[2]); }`?  In fact, if you know how many arguments it will take, you don't need the (unused) `n` parameter.  But this must be simpler than what you're asking for...so, are you seeking a way to generate a functions of this general nature?  Will the functions all return `double`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "yes" to all questions, i can't unuse n because in fact i don't know what function is in a func, i just only know that it returns double and has n double parameters

Comment: @Solon That's why I said it would be messy.

Comment: I feel this is an XY question - you are asking how to solve the problem with what you think is a solution. But the actual problem you are trying to solve is something else, and I'm pretty sure we can come up with a better solution if we understand the whole problem setup.

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is that you have to cast the pointer differently depending on the number of argument (i.e. depending on the `n` variable).

One way is to use a wrapper-function containing a `switch` statement for the argument number:

```
double wrapper(void *func, double args[], int n)
{
    switch (n)
    {
    case 0:
        return ((double (*)(void)) func)();
    case 1:
        return ((double (*)(double)) func)(args[0]);
    case 2:
        return ((double (*)(double, double)) func)(args[0], args[1]);
    case 3:
        return ((double (*)(double, double, double)) func)(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
    default:
        printf("Error: wrapper called with %d arguments\n", n)
        break;
    }

    return 0.0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*Written late last night — but my Internet connection went down as I tried to post it.  I see Joachim has written essentially the same answer.*

---

Within limits, this will work:

```
#include <assert.h>

extern double function_invoker(void *func, int n, double *values);

double function_invoker(void *func, int n, double *values)
{
    switch (n)
    {
    case 0:
        return (*(double (*)(void))func)();
    case 1:
        return (*(double (*)(double))func)(values[0]);
    case 2:
        return (*(double (*)(double, double))func)(values[0], values[1]);
    case 3:
        return (*(double (*)(double, double, double))func)(values[0], values[1], values[2]);
    default:
        assert("Need more entries in the switch in function_invoker()" == 0);
        return(0.0);
    }
}
```

The obvious limits are how many entries you want to make in the `switch`.  I've seen loosely analogous code go up to over 100 arguments; I'm not sure why that was considered necessary.

That code compiles without warnings under GCC 4.6.0 on Mac OS X 10.8.2:

```
$ gcc -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition -c x.c
$
```

But if you go with `double (*)()` in place of `void *`, you get:

```
$ gcc -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition -c x.c
x.c:3:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
x.c:5:1: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
$
```

Comment: Great minds and all that... :) But I think you switched the two compilation outputs?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: There was a bug in my function declaration, but (rather to my surprise), the `void *` function compiles without warnings but the more nearly honest `double (*)()` function generates the (expected) warnings for me.  I double checked with GCC 4.7.1 and an Apple-create GCC 4.2.1 and both gave a clean bill of health to the `void *` version.